# Python Scatterplot: Same colors not touching

Tags: python, data-visualization, cluster-analysis, graph-coloring

Consider the following scatter plot.

```py
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

k = load_iris().data[:,:2]
_ = sns.scatterplot(x=k[:,0], y=k[:,1])
```

[image]

Let's say I ran a clustering algorithm over this dataset, that has only two features/dimensions x and y. The clustering algorithm yields a cluster id for each point in the scatter plot. The cluster id is in [1..N]. I'd like to color each point differently (with the color according to its id), but, since N is quite large (N > 50), I run out of visually distinguishable colors.

Say, I am only given M visually distinguishable colors (4 <= M <= 20). I'd like to find a coloring such that no two identical colors in the scatterplot "touch". With touch I mean "are next to each other" or "there is an unobstructed line of sight between them".

I know that this is solvable since any planar graph is four colorable and finding a graph coloring is already implemented in python (e.g. networkx). How would I go about this?

Comment: It's hard to understand the purpose of this, if you are using something like `.5*n` colors to  represent `n` distinct clusters, would it not defeat the purpose of the color coding?

Answer (score 3):

You could generate a matrix that consists of a rotating list of colors that you arrange in such a way that none of them touch, then use that as the point colors.

```
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from collections import deque

sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(16,9)})

k = load_iris().data[:,:2]

# Create a 100*100 matrix with no adjacent values
m = []
l = deque(['r','g','b','y']*25)

for x in range(100):
    m.append(list(l))
    l.rotate(2)

# Create color map by using values as coordinates to select
# from color matrix
colors = []
for e in k:
    p = [(int(str(x).replace('.',''))) for x in e]
    colors.append(m[p[0]][p[1]])
    
# Plot using colors from color map    
_ = sns.scatterplot(x=k[:,0], y=k[:,1], c=colors, s=250)
```

[image]